# Can I call one CakePHP shell from another?

Tags: cakephp, shell

I have a CakePHP shell program called 'match', which runs through my database performing some fairly complicated stuff.

I'm writing another shell so I can do some proof-of-concept simulation, this shell is called 'simulate'.

I need 'simulate' to be able to call 'match', then continue running. As the simulation will 
repeat many different scenarios over and over, manually running 'match' is not an option.

I've tried to App::import('shell','match'), but to no avail.

Help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could move the shared functionality into a task and then call this task from both shells, see http://book.cakephp.org/view/1109/Tasks

Answer (score 2):

You could use `$this->dispatchShell` to run another cake shell.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html